# How to configure SSIS merge Join transformation

Tags: sql-server, ssis

[image]

The Excel Source has a column (ExcelColumn1) of type Unicode text stream[DT_NTEXT] and  the OLE DB Source has a column(SQLColumn1) of type Unicode string[DT_WSTR]

I want to match and merge join results from the above two sources where

> ExcelColumn1 = SQLColumn1

I have right clicked both sources, went to thier Advanced Editor dialogues, then to their input and output properties, then output columns, then the columns i want to sort by and set their sortkeyPosition from 0 to 1.

The isSorted property for both sources has also been set to True, but when i double click the Merge Join so i can configure the columns on which to join on, i am getting the error in the screenshot below. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drag a Sort component for both the inputs : the sortid should be the same on the columns where you make a join,then configure merge join component.

see these links

1.http://www.bimonkey.com/2010/10/the-merge-join-transformation/

2.http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1322/merge-multiple-data-sources-with-sql-server-integration-services/

If the error is with mismatch data type drag a Type conversion component and try joining with `copy of column` with other input !

Comment: i have tried converting both columns to the same datatype using the Data Conversion transformations but the error has persisted.

Comment: If you are sure that Excel input is sorted and SQL you can use [ASC] to sort the data. You can set IsSorted property in advanced editor of the datasource. So that you can avoid sort transformation [blocking transformation]